# Ratio values groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Here is a DataFrame where I use the `groupby()` function to obtain the number of positive and negative occurrences per day.

```
data = [['28-08-22', 'Positive'], ['28-08-22', 'Negative'],  ['28-08-22', 'Positive'], ['28-08-22', 'Positive'], ['27-08-22', 'Positive'], ['27-08-22', 'Negative'], ['27-08-22', 'Negative'], ['27-08-22', 'Negative']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'actions'])
df2 = df.groupby('Date')['actions'].value_counts(normalize=True)

print(df2)
```

I would like to calculate the ratio of those occurrences for each day, meaning dividing `positive value / negative value` for each day.

[Output and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8JtK.png)

Also, if on a day the positive value is higher than the negative one, I would like the ratio to be positive. If the negative value is higher than the positive, I would like the ratio to be negative.

I am new to python so definitely need your help. Thank you!

Comment: Sample toy data would be helpful.

Also, it's not clear whether your code already works and you are just looking for alternatives, or if it doesn't, and you need a working version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following instead of calculation df2:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='actions',aggfunc='size').reset_index().set_index('Date')

df['percent'] = df['Negative'] / df.sum(axis=1)
```